# Winclone to volume not bootable

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup

I'm trying to move my Windows 10 Boot Camp partition to an external drive. The ideal way seems to be with Winclone, however I've been unsuccessful so far.

Winclone appears to clone the partition to the external disk successfully and does not report any errors, but upon ⌥-booting, **the disk is not shown in the Startup Manager**.

Windows 10 is up-to-date and chkdsk has been run on both the Boot Camp partition (disk0s4) prior to cloning and the external disk (disk1s2) post-cloning. The external disk is GUID as Winclone informs me this is required when attempting to clone to an MBR partition scheme.

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Mac SSD                 150.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data Windows                 100.1 GB   disk0s4
/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data Windows                 499.9 GB   disk1s2
```

```
$ sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk1
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640       2008         
     411648  976355328      2  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  976766976       2015         
  976768991         32         Sec GPT table
  976769023          1         Sec GPT header  
$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk1
Disk: /dev/disk1    geometry: 60801/255/63 [976769024 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -  976769023] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

```
$ sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  292968736      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  293378376    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  294647912       1944         
  294649856  195584000      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  490233856        863         
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk0      
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 30515/255/63 [490234752 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
 2: AF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  292968736] HFS+        
 3: AB 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 293378376 -    1269536] Darwin Boot 
*4: 0C 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 294649856 -  195584000] Win95 FAT32L
```

How can I make the external disk bootable?

MacBookPro10,1 (Retina, Mid 2012)

Comment: don't think it's a dupe, but is this any help? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49004/install-windows-7-on-external-drive-and-boot-it-from-a-mac

Comment: @Tetsujin I'd like to avoid reinstalling Windows if at all possible, but cheers.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the model/year of your Mac.

Comment: I assume this is the link to Winclone's instructions: [Migrate Windows 8 or higher to an External Drive](https://twocanoes.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203443727-Migrate-Windows-8-or-higher-to-an-External-Drive-)

Comment: @David These are the instructions I followed.

Comment: Do you know if Windows is booting internally in EFI or MBR mode? Do you have the basic or Standard version of Winclone. In other words, did you buy the edition with features for migrating Windows to external disks?

Comment: [Running Windows from an External Drive](https://twocanoes.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205025389-Considerations-for-Booting-Windows-from-an-External-Drive): 3. Full EFI compliant firmware on the Mac computer. With some exceptions, late 2013 Macs and newer are UEFI 2.0-compliant.

Comment: If you read the comments made my Rod Smith and Windoze at [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/650623/boot-ubuntu-from-external-usb-hdd-on-retina-macbookpro-2015) , you will learn that even 2015 Mac Book Pro's are not UEFI 2.0 compliant

Comment: @David I'm using an edu version of Winclone Pro which supports migrating Windows to external disks. MacBookPro10 is included in the list of PreUEFIModels in your link — what am I supposed to infer from this?

Comment: @klanomath Does this mean it's not possible?

Comment: @grgarside I think it's possible but not in EFI boot mode. I can't verify this though, because I have no spare Mac to test this. It's probably hacky... And you probably need an Enterprise/Education version to access the Windows to Go feature.

Comment: A user has posted a question where he claims to have run Windows 10 on an external disk. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244220/best-way-of-running-windows-on-a-macexternal-ssd). He has the same Mac model as your computer. He was not able to get a EFI install to work properly, therefore he used the BIOS boot method. This required booting from a small partition on the internal disk, then transferring control to the external disk. Do you need Windows to reside completely on your external disk?

Comment: Does the Windows 10 installed on your internal disk boot using the EFI or legacy BIOS method? If you do not know how to determine this, a test is given at [Does Windows, running on latest Apple computers, see boot disk partitioned as MBR or GPT?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169680/does-windows-running-on-latest-apple-computers-see-boot-disk-partitioned-as-mb). If MBR, then you are using the BIOS method. If GPT, then you are using the EFI method.

Comment: @David Apologies, I missed these comments; thanks for getting back to me. I do already have Windows 10 on an external disk which I set up without any trouble and which boots fine, without any partition on the internal disk or any trickery like that — I can move the external disk to a different computer, hold ⌥ and boot it just fine. I'm just having difficulty moving the Boot Camp partition. I used the Boot Camp Assistant to set up the partition on the internal disk, and the steps in the link in your second comment tell me it's MBR (gpt on disk0 output included above shows it's hybrid MBR).

Comment: What does "I'm just having difficulty moving the Boot Camp partition" mean. Do you mean to say: "I'm just having difficulty ***removing*** the Boot Camp partition."?

Comment: @David I'm just referring to the original question of taking the Windows partition and copying it to an external drive whilst having it bootable. I can delete the existing partition on my internal disk fine and expand OS X. It's just I'm not able to make the external disk bootable. Just because I might not have been clear previously, my previous comment was referring to a completely different external disk with a fresh, separate install of Windows for a different purpose. It's my current install of Windows internally that I'd like to be able to boot from an external disk.